# how to calculate the page of a newly added record of jqgrid using php

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I have problem calculating page number for newly added record for jqgrid in the back end so that i can focus on that row when the grid is reloaded. can anyone tell me the logic to do it?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new row then it automatically generate page no and all.
i don't know how you implemented jqgrid.can you show your code here .